# Auto-complete feature for Texmaker citations

Tags: biblatex, citing, texmaker, auto-completion

I have Texmaker 4.1.1 and autocomplete feature for citations doesn't work in it. I have my .bib file in the correct directory (the same as my `.tex` file), use `biblatex`, have added the command `\addbibresource{<my .bib file>}` in the correct place in the `.tex` file, and have already tried refreshing bibliography from Edit menu. Could you suggest some way to fix this?

Comment: `Options`-->`Configure Texmaker`-->`Editor`-->Is `completion` checked on  and add `.bib` extension [`\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib). Check if you can see bib `file-name` in `Structure` on left side pane.

Comment: @texenthusiast  Why not add an answer? :)

Comment: @HarishKumar Just to be safe, I am waiting reply from OP if my suggestion worked.

Comment: @texenthusiast Some times (actually most of the times) you won't get reply if it works ;). Hence make it an answer :)

Comment: @texenthusiast Thank you for your help. I had already added the .bib file as the argument of addbibresource. But I checked if the settings for 'completion' which I found under the User menu was appropriate and it was strange for me why without changing any settings it started to work by accident. Just in case it may be useful to someone, i want to add that for making sure if 'bib file-name' appears in Structure on left side pane, one can also open the file with Texmaker from File menu. Thanks again :)

Comment: I double checked and yes the Completion checkbox does appear here: Options-->Configure Texmaker-->Editor

Comment: I found that closing and oppening the programme works really well. Be sure to try that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Made comment into answer which satisfied the OP

`Options`-->`Configure Texmaker`-->`Editor`--> Is `completion` checked on and add `.bib` extension `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}`. Check if you can see `.bib` file in Structure on left side pane or open the `.bib` file with Texmaker from File menu.

Comment: Sometimes I need to also press `Edit` -> `Refresh Bibliography` to make the new entries appear. (Alt-E, <Up>, <Enter>)

Comment: worth mentioning that this `Refresh Bibliography` trick needs to be done in Master in order to work, not in another script with e.g. sections.

Comment: How would this work when using `\bibliography{}` instead?

Answer (score 2):

I found it out now after several tests. I have the following **file** for all bibliography stuff:

```
\renewcommand{\bibname} {C Literaturverzeichnis} 
\bibliographystyle{alphadin} 
\bibliography{bibtex/entries} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bibname}
```

And I had the same issue like you. Everything is working and the bibliography and literature is **correctly referenced**. But I do **not** have any cite **popup**/**sugguestion**.

So the only thing I needed to do to always get it working, was opening the file with the **commands** above and one time hit **compile**. Now I always get the cite popups again.

I don't know to do that automatically, but at least it's working again now. Maybe someone could share how to do that?

Comment: Well it's a currently working solution. It just contains a question but that question is not needed to fix the issues. And the other solution above did not work when I was trying it right now. So I decided to show my solution here. Where is the problem guys?

Comment: I don't understand this answer since you are referencing only names and not what they should be. What should be the second argument in `\renewcommand{\bibname}{someDirectoryQuestionmark}`.

Also `addcontentsline` seems like it would do something completely different and unrelated but it is related somehow? (I am not using a table of contents so it would be weird I would have to act on it.)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 and MikTex(basic-miktex-2.9.5105)+TexMaker4.3+bibtex file, I found that if I use command like these:

`\bibliographystyle{bst file name}
\bibliography {bib file name}`

then \cite will not auto-complete.

yet however if I use command like these:

`\bibliographystyle{bst file name}
\bibliography{bib file name}`

then \cite will auto-complete the reference normally.

The only difference is that there is a space between \bibliography and {bib file name} or not.

It should be noted that both of the above could display the reference in article normally.

Comment: Actually, for me on Windows 10 the opposite worked. Without the space, i.e. `\bibliography{bib file name}`, the auto-completion was not working. By adding the space and recompiling, the auto-completion worked. After this, I removed the space and compiled again, and the auto-completion was still working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to load the `.bib` file from your master document (root `.tex` file), loading it from and `\input` or `\include` will cause trouble.

It would look something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{memoir}
    \input{Preamble}
    \bibliography{BIBLIOGRAPHY} % load the .bib here.
\begin{document}
    \cite{what ever} % should now run with auto compile.
\end{document}
```

Obv, you should remember to load BibLaTeX and set styles in your preamble.

Comment: I don't think that `\bibliography` in the preamble will give the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is

```
Options-->Configure Texmaker-->Editor
```

and then check the checkbox near "check for external changes"

Answer (score 0):

I had to add .bib to the name of the bibliography file:

so instead of \bibliography{bibliographyfilename} I have \bibliography{bibliographyfilename.bib} and now it works...

Good luck