# Citet command not an option for Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, citing, biber

I am a bit new to LaTeX etc. so please excuse me if this is a beginner question.

I would like to cite references within my document in the following style:

> According to Powell et al. (2007)...
>
> This is the best way to do it (Powell et al., 2007)

And so forth. To the best of my understanding, I want to use `authoryear` style to achieve this. The problem I'm having is getting the first result with the year in parentheses.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
maxcitenames=2,
bibencoding=latin1
]
{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

 @article{powell2007fastfood,
 title={The availability of fast-food and full-service restaurants in 
 the United States: associations with neighborhood characteristics},
 author={Powell, Lisa M and Chaloupka, Frank J and Bao, Yanjun},
 journal={American journal of preventive medicine},
 volume={33},
 number={4},
 pages={S240--S245},
 year={2007},
 publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Here you see \cite{powell2007fastfood}
Here you can also see \parencite{powell2007fastfood}
Also, you have \textcite{powell2007fastfood}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

So the first two, `\cite` and `\parencite`, work. They produce the desired results of:

> Here you see Powell et al. 2007
>
> Here you can also see (Powell et al. 2007)

For `\textcite`, I have to manually type it in (using Texmaker provides an autocomplete or autosuggestion option) and then once I have typed the command, I also have to manually type the citation ID. Then when I compile, it gives me the error message "undefined control sequence." It's like the `\textcite` command is simply not recognized at all. What could cause this?

As an aside, I would prefer a style that put a comma between the author/et al. and year, so

> Powell et al., 2007

But I am also trying to explore different citation styles to get what I want.

Comment: `\textcite` should work. You'll have to show us a complete example with the problem. Take a look at [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) and [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to have an idea on how to prepare one.

Comment: `\citet` (t at the ending of the command!) and `\citep` are defined with `natbib` To be able to use them add option`natbib` to `biblatex`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have added an example. I hope that's enough for a MWE. I can also explore the `natbib` option.

Comment: The code shown so far is unfortunately not an MWE. Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407 to find out what makes an MWE. If I try to complete the code snippets into an MWE (https://gist.github.com/moewew/485cd2ecdaea88acca9f5c9b97227a00) the output is exactly as expected. Please turn your code into an MWE, run that MWE and copy and paste the error message you get from `\textcite`.

Comment: I finally figured it out, although I'm still not sure why. A series of restarts and reopens. Although I still do not get an autocomplete suggestion for the command, and when I type `\textcite` it still does not offer me a list of references to choose from like the other commands. But at least it is compiling as desired now.

Comment: For the autocomplete you may want to look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436207/35864. Or use an editor with more built-in autocomplete commands (TeXstudio comes to mind).

Comment: Thank you @moewe I will check out TeXstudio. I really do value the autocomplete commands.

Comment: Note that my advice in that respect is mostly hearsay: I use neither TeXstudio nor TeXmaker productively myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most `biblatex` styles offer a variety of citation commands. You can find what all standard styles and therefore most contributed styles do in §3.8 *Citation Commands* and its subsections, pp. 100-110, of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

The following example shows the most common citation commands for `authoryear` styles

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}

\cite{sigfridsson}

\parencite{sigfridsson}

\textcite{sigfridsson}

Lorem\footcite{sigfridsson}

\fullcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998)//Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998//(Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998)//Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998)//Lorem footnote 1 to a full citation like the following//Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P]

The behaviour of the `\autocite` commands, whose use I can't recommend enough, can be configured freely. By default it behaves like `\parencite` or `\footcite` for most standard styles (it will behave like `\footcite` for styles of the `authortitle` and `verbose` style families and like `\parencite` for most other styles). But you can easily switch to footnote citation should you want to. Just have a look at the `autocite` option.

It does not matter whether or not those commands show up in some autocompletion feature of your editor. They are defined by all `biblatex` standard styles and all good contributed styles and should therefore work. If your editor's autocompletion does not display these commands, then that is something you can take up with the developers of the editor or the author of the autocomplete function. (But see also [Auto-complete feature for Texmaker citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161275/35864), [Biblatex - Texmaker auto-complete commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436207/35864).)

There is the `natbib` compatibility option that lets you use `natbib`'s equivalent shorter names for `\parencite` and `\textcite` (namely `\citep` and `\citet`, respectively). I would normally try to avoid using that option since the handling of the starred forms of citation commands differ for the `biblatex` and the `natbib` names. Furthermore, the `natbib` compatibility mode changes the definition of `nameyeardelim`, which means that there will be a comma between author and year in `\cite` and `\parencite`/`\citep`. See also [Is there a disadvantage to using natbib=true with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149313/35864).

---

If you want to see a comma between author and year you can just set

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

the `natbib` compatibility mode is not required for that.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Actually, reading through it, I would prefer a comma between author and year. Perhaps I should explore natbib. I am very new to bibliography options here. Having not gotten too far along in my current document, it may not be as cumbersome to switch?

Comment: @Bkk There is a (huge) difference between switching to `natbib` altogether and using the `natbib` compatibility option. In general I would suggest to stick with `biblatex` and only use the `natbib` compatibility option if you want to retain the old `natbib` names for compatibility with older documents. But there might be reasons to prefer `natbib` (if you have to use an existing `.bst` file or submit to a journal). You may be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864

Comment: Thank you for the edit on how to put a comma in. That's hugely helpful. After reading the link and your suggestion, I will stick with not using `natbib`.

Comment: "The behaviour of the `\autocite` commands, whose use I can't recommend enough, can be configured freely, by default it behaves like `\autocite`." Did you mean "it behaves like `\parencite`"?

Comment: @BrtH Yup. Typo fixed and passage slightly clarified. Thanks for the hint.